# Python programming , calculate the class frequency

Tags: python

```
k=np.array(
    [[1, 0, 0],
     [0, 1, 1],
     [1, 0, 1],
     [1, 1, 1],
     [1, 0, 1]]
)
```

In this array, how can I compute the frequency of each column 
For example :
If I need positive case, the output should be [4,2,4] 
If I need negative case , the output should be [2,3,1]

Comment: I don't know. You tell me.

Comment: are you referring to counts across rows   for the different symbols?  So [1,3,1] for the zeros?

Answer (score 0):

If it's just these two numeric symbols (meaning you can treat them as numbers).

```
import numpy as np
k=np.array(
    [[1, 0, 0],
     [0, 1, 1],
     [1, 0, 1],
     [1, 1, 1],
     [1, 0, 1]]
)
print(np.sum(k,axis=0))
print(np.sum(1-k,axis=0))
```

output:

[4 2 4]

[1 3 1]